# How to specialise trait implementations for different type parameters?

Tags: rust

I need to call some logic that is specific to type parameter. How can I achieve that?

I try the following code:

```rust
trait Conn {}

struct SqliteConn;
struct PostgreConn;

impl Conn for SqliteConn {}
impl Conn for PostgreConn {}

trait Data {
    fn init(&mut self);
}

struct Db<C: Conn> {
    conn: C,
}

impl<C: Conn> Db<C> {
    fn new(conn: C) -> Self {
        let mut db = Self { conn };
        db.init(); // fails here
        db
    }
}

impl Data for Db<SqliteConn> {
    fn init(&mut self) {
        // sqlite3-specific init
    }
}

impl Data for Db<PostgreConn> {
    fn init(&mut self) {
        // postgre-specific init
    }
}
```

Rust compiler complains with "no method named `init` found for struct `Db` in the current scope" error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require that `Db<C>` has an implementation of `Data`, which you can do with `where`:

```
impl <C: Conn> Db<C> where Db<C>: Data {
  fn new(conn: C) -> Self {
    let mut db = Self { conn };
    db.init();
    db
  }
}
```